# Using Facebook APIs for comment statistics

Tags: .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, comments

Is it possible to use the Facebook API with .NET in order to retrieve number of comments that users make on a specific page on my site?

Also is it possible to change the look and feel of Facebook comments with these API's?

Answer (score 0):

Start here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/ 
Look at the FAQ at the bottom, it shows how to retrieve the comments